# How to add google maps object from GWT code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, jsni

I would like to use google maps in my GWT application. The thing is that the gwt-maps API only supports Google Maps API version 2, and the regular maps api is version 3. So basically what I want to do is to use the standart js maps library from my GWT code, but this doesn't work:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
        buildMap();
    }



    private final native void buildMap()/*-{



         <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

        }-*/;
```

I suspect that the problem is that onModuleLoad is not equivalent to body.onload. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

The first thing I did was to create a UIBinder to hold the div of the map:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And here is the rest of the code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    mapCanvas canvas = new mapCanvas();
    Document.get().getBody().appendChild(canvas.getElement());
    buildMap();
}   


private final native void buildMap()/*-{
    var latlng = new $wnd.google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: $wnd.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new $wnd.google.maps.Map($doc.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}-*/;
```

Comment: ...why are you using a <div> element? Why not use one of the many, many available panels that _act_ like <div> but provide native access?

Comment: Well, first of all I am new to GWT and I just wanted to create a simple JSNI example of google maps that works... Right now I don't know how to access a Panel from a JSNI block.

Comment: Ok, and why do you want to use JSNI when there are built-in Maps API wrappers to make your life easier? Seems like you're creating code that will be a massive pain to maintain when you have the option not to. Use the wrapper, save yourself the stress of having to manually find bugs in code you can't step through. Read my answer posted below.

Comment: I would gladly use anything that would make my life easier :) First, I wanted to use the official gwt-maps api but it only supports v2 of google maps. gwt-google-maps-v3 is definitely good, but unfortunately it's deprecated so I would check the code there for my implementations but I wouldn't want to use the code "blindly". There are many developers out there that don't use GWT at all and use just js for google maps, and once I get to know JSNI better it won't really be any different.

Comment: It's deprecated because it's being merged into gwt-google-apis. Nothing will change with the code. The _project_ is deprecated, not the code.

Comment: The site for google-maps-api-v3 states clearly that some features are not available. Apparently, stating "this is merging into the apis" means "we don't have to provide useful documentation". I had to view the source directory to even see that there were classes for Markers and InfoWindows.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [gwt-google-maps-v3](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/), the open source wrapper for version 3 of the Maps API. The project is technically deprecated because it's being merged with gwt-google-apis, but it'll at least get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I have a whole app to do this. Check out the project at https://github.com/dartmanx/mapmaker/tree/0.5.2

You may want to pay special attention to my utility class for Google Maps:

https://github.com/dartmanx/mapmaker/blob/0.5.2/src/main/java/org/jason/mapmaker/client/util/GoogleMapUtil.java

Hope it helps, I went through alot of pain with that JSNI.

Jason

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely check this out.